# key value coding-compliant for NSObject class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I've created a singleton class that loads a plist.  I keep getting this error when I try to set a value:

`[<MyPlist 0x1917bc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:` this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'

I have one key in the plist file.  The key is named "test" and has no value associated with it.  I set the value like this:

```
[[PlistManager sharedManager].plist setValue:@"the title value" forKey:@"test"];
```

I look at the set plist dictionary and see this from within PlistManager:

```
po self.plistDictionary
{
  test = "";
}
```

I get the error just as I'm leaving PlistManager in the debugger. PlistManager is of type NSObject.  So no xibs.  Any ideas on what I need to do?

Comment: Is the plist member an NSDictionary?

Comment: Note that if `plist` is actually an `NSMutableDictionary`, it will be more efficient to use `setObject:forKey:` than `setValue:forKey:`, though both will work.

Comment: @Barry: Are you sure that's still true? I think that NSDictionary belongs to the classes that are quite well optimized.

Comment: @Georg: I would expect it to be well optimized, but the docs state that valueForKey:/setValue:forKey: does a little extra processing on the keys before invoking objectForKey:/setObject:forKey:, so it has to be at least slightly less efficient. As always, profile your code to decide if the difference maters!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could it be that you are using a non-mutable dictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary?